# how to define a method in warriorjs game in ecmascript 6?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm learning nodejs with [warriorjs](https://github.com/olistic/warriorjs) game. It's give me a simple class:

```
class Player {
    playTurn(warrior) {
    }
}
global.Player = Player;
```

So I want to make a method for Player class. For instance:

```
class Player {
    playTurn(warrior) {
        foo();
    }

    playTurn(warrior) {
        foo();
    }

    foo() {}
}
global.Player = Player;
```

I thought it is the way to create a method in js but it give error:

```
undefined:25
      foo();
      ^
ReferenceError: foo is not defined
    at Player.playTurn (eval at loadPlayer (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Level.js:155:94), <anonymous>:25:7)
    at Warrior.playTurn (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/units/Warrior.js:38:24)
    at Warrior.prepareTurn (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/units/Base.js:280:12)
    at /usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Level.js:177:23
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Level.play (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Level.js:176:36)
    at Game.playCurrentLevel (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Game.js:130:30)
    at Game.playNormalMode (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Game.js:120:16)
    at Game.start (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Game.js:70:14)
    at Runner.run (/usr/lib64/node_modules/warriorjs/lib/Runner.js:42:18)
```

Anybody can help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `this.`, because `.foo` is `Player's` method, not *global* function

```
playTurn(warrior) {
  this.foo();
}
```

if you want call `foo` without `.this`, you need add `foo` function, like so

```
function foo() {

} 

class Player {
    playTurn(warrior) {
        foo();
    }

    playTurn(warrior) {
        foo();
    }
}

global.Player = Player;
```

Comment: Thank you. How I forget to give 'this' a try before

Answer (score 2):

You should only need to call it with `this.foo()`